# WAMP redirect to phpmyadmin homepage when clicked on link

Tags: apache, codeigniter, wamp

I load my web project into a freshly installed wamp application and when I clicked on the links to my other pages of the website, it was directed to the phpmyadmin homepage. My web project is developed using codeigniter framework.

According to the apache error log,

> [Wed Dec 12 16:56:38 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/wamp/www/mathplication/about, referer:
>    [Wed Dec 12 16:56:40 2012] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/assets

in the htacess file, the content is as below

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /mathplication/   #RewriteBase /
>
> #Removes access to the system folder by users.
> #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
> #previously this would not have been possible.
> #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
>
> #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
> #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
> #Submitted by: Fabdrol
> #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
>
> #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
> #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
> #request to index.php
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] </IfModule>
> ```

but the error still remains.

Not sure what else can I check for. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: so you are saying it's because of .htaccess file

Comment: oh I am not sure where the problem lies. But when I googled about it, most of them referred to .htaccess file.

Comment: k try with the code which i am posting it as answer........if it didn't work let me know............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code............

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Remove all other things in the `.htaccess` file